# Why is DOSBox Emulator completely destroying my display settings?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, games, dosbox

I recently installed the DosBox emulator to play some retro games (mostly Zork). Every time I open it, I move to fullscreen by pressing Alt+Enter and play some of a game. Whenever I exit the game afterwards, the following display settings have been corrupted:

1: The two monitors I have are now detected as one monitor, therefore it is permanently set to mirror displays, though I had it set to joining the displays previously.

2: The enire screen is zoomed in severely, making it hard to navigate through anything.

3: It appears I can't type anything while this is going on?

The only way for me to fix this issue is to reboot the computer, which is not nice considering how long it takes for my computer to boot. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a very old question, and is about DOSBox, not Ubuntu.

Comment: It's relevant to Ubuntu because the only official dosbox package in Ubuntu repositories is buggy. I suggest keeping the question up, as it affects every Ubuntu / Linux user relying on vanilla dosbox.

Comment: @SyntheticHuman - I can hardly figure a more pertinent question for this site. Running emulators and ensure portability of "foreign" software is a basic requirement for a platform with the ambition to reach a large market share. OMG! You're asking to close your own question? You and Patryk just made my day, let's keep it!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

That's because DOSBox uses SDL 1.2 - old, unmaintained library which does not work well on modern Linux. To prevent this problem, use version of DOSBox ported to SDL2, e.g. [DOSBox Staging](https://dosbox-staging.github.io/).

Available via [PPA](https://dosbox-staging.github.io/downloads/linux/#ubuntu-mint) or [Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/dosbox-staging).